# Is there a textboxlist control available somewhere?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textboxlist

There are ASP controls such as radiobuttonlist and checkboxlist and you can databind them to a database query. It's great for creating dynamic lists with user interaction. What I'm trying to do is generate a list of textboxes in the same fashion. A list of textboxes that behave the same way.

The object is to have a checkboxlist that is generated via datasource/database. When the user is finished selecting items from this list, they click a button. That list hides (using jquery) and a new list is created based on their selections. However, the new list is now a list of their selections accompanied by an empty textbox. The user fills in the textboxes for each entry and submits again which commits it to a database.

SO:

```
checkbox - description
checkbox - description
checkbox - description
checkbox - description
```

Becomes:

```
Description - Textbox
Description - Textbox
```

The reason that I'm looking for a list-type control is so that I can ultimately loop through it for submission to the database using linq. Does that make sense? My real question is if there is a control like this yet. I gave the full description in case someone has any other ideas, short of creating a custom control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing out of the box that does what you describe no. But you can still loop through controls. I would put your form controls inside of an asp:Panel or a div with runat="server" and use something like the following code to cycle through them as you described.

```
foreach(Control ctl in myPanel.Controls)
{
  //check control type and handle
  if (ctl is TextBox)
  {
     //handle the control and its value here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

asp:ListBox has a property named SelectionMode, which can be set to SelectionMode="Multiple" and allows you to select items you want. This is not exactly what you need but it's a simple solution.

Comment: that only proposes another option for the first step. My concern is with the second step which involves a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

After the selection is made in checkboxlist, make a postback to server. Here create a datatable with two columns (description & text). For every selected item in the checkboxlist add a row to this table and bind it to a gridview control. Here 'text' column will be always empty. Configure the gridview to use template column with a textbox in the itemtemplate