# How to Dynamically create textboxes using ASP.NET and then save their values in Database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a survey site.  I want to add the textboxes dynamically and then get their values in the database.

Now let's say I select 4 textboxes from the dropdown to be there dynamically.

**Code on the Selection on dropdown :**

```
     protected void NumDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "TextBox")
        {

            int j;
            i = int.Parse(NumDropDown.SelectedValue);
            Session["i"] = i;
            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                    t = new TextBox[i];
                    Session["textBox"] = t;
                    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                    {
                        t[j] = new TextBox();
                        t[j].ID = "txtCheckbox" + j.ToString();
                        Panel1.Controls.Add(t[j]);

                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    t = new TextBox[i];
                    Session["textBox"] = t;
                    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                    {
                        t[j] = new TextBox();
                        t[j].ID = "txtCheckbox" + j.ToString();
                        Panel1.Controls.Add(t[j]);

                    }
                    break;

                case 3:
                    t = new TextBox[i];
                    Session["textBox"] = t;
                    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                    {
                        t[j] = new TextBox();
                        t[j].ID = "txtCheckbox" + j.ToString();
                        Panel1.Controls.Add(t[j]);

                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    t = new TextBox[i];
                    List<TextBox> MyTextBoxes;
                    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                    {
                        t[j] = new TextBox();
                        t[j].ID = "txtCheckbox" + j.ToString();
                        Panel1.Controls.Add(t[j]);
                        try
                        {
                            MyTextBoxes = (List<TextBox>)Session["AddedTextBox"];
                            MyTextBoxes.Add(t[j]);
                            Session["AddedTextBox"] = MyTextBoxes;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            MyTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
                            MyTextBoxes.Add(t[j]);
                            Session["AddedTextBox"] = MyTextBoxes;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
```

2) Then Here I entered the values in the textBox like a, b,c,d and click ADD:

**Code for the click On the ADD Click :**

1) First i checked the session to be there on Page_Init :

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["AddedTextBox"] != null)
        {
            string a;
            string b;
            string c;
            string d;

            int listCount = ((List<TextBox>)Session["AddedTextBox"]).Count;
            foreach (TextBox t in ((List<TextBox>)Session["AddedTextBox"]))
            {
                if (listCount == 1)
                {

                }
                if (listCount == 2)
                {

                }
                if (listCount == 3)
                {

                }
                if (listCount == 4)
                {
                    if (t.ID == "txtCheckbox0")
                    {
                        a = t.Text;
                    }
                    if (t.ID == "txtCheckbox0")
                    {
                        b = t.Text;
                    }
                    if (t.ID == "txtCheckbox0")
                    {
                        c = t.Text;
                    }
                    if (t.ID == "txtCheckbox0")
                    {
                        d = t.Text;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

But the problem here is that I don't get the text values, they Appear to be empty.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: you may benefit from the approach mentioned here: [Is there a textboxlist control available somewhere?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070327/is-there-a-textboxlist-control-available-somewhere)

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like the age-old classic problem with asp.net adding controls dynamically to a page.

The problem is to with viewstate and reconstruction of the controls on postback.

You need to run the same code that generated the controls on postback ***at the correct time in the page lifecycle*** to ensure postback values match server-side controls.

Of course if you want a hacky shortcut, access the `Request.Form["textCheckbox" + index]` values directly

[A useful article on the subject.](https://web.archive.org/web/20210330142645/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As @jenson-button-event mentioned you can access the `TextBox` values through `Request.Form` here's an example:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTextBoxes" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="5" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="Add" /><br />
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="container" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

**Code behind:**

```
    protected void Add(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int numOfTxt = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTextBoxes.SelectedItem.Value);
        var table = new Table();

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfTxt; i++)
        {
            var row = new TableRow();
            var cell = new TableCell();

            TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
            textbox.ID = "Textbox" + i;
            textbox.Width = new Unit(180);

            cell.Controls.Add(textbox);
            row.Cells.Add(cell);
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        container.Controls.AddAt(0,table);
        container.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textboxValues = new List<string>();
        if (Request.Form.HasKeys())
        {
            Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(i => i.Contains("Textbox")).ToList().ForEach(i =>
                {
                    textboxValues.Add(Request.Form[i]);
                });
        }

        //Do something with the textbox values
        textboxValues.ForEach(i => Response.Write(i + "<br />"));
        container.Visible = false;
    }
```